# How to read binary data in Bytes Using Apache MINA Server?

Tags: java, client-server, serversocket, apache-mina, mina

Here I am reading Binary data, but this gives me
 "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.mina.core.buffer.IoBuffer"

**IoBuffer buffer = (IoBuffer) message;** // Exception at This line

```
IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();

            acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
            acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast(
                    "codec",
                    new ProtocolCodecFilter(new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset
                            .forName("ISO-8859-1"))));
    @Override
        public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message)
                throws Exception {
    IoBuffer buffer = (IoBuffer) message;
                b = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue as it assigned string values to IOBuffer `IoBuffer buffer = (IoBuffer) message;`. You can't assign directly.
You have to use `putString` method for it. I have added little sample. I don't know what you are doing but this may help you.

```
String message=(String)message;
IoBuffer buf = IoBuffer.allocate(message.length()).setAutoExpand(true);
buf.putString(message, ENCODER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Done like this:

```
IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();

            acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
            acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast(
                    "codec",
                    new ProtocolCodecFilter(new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset
                            .forName("ISO-8859-1"))));
    @Override
        public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message)
                throws Exception {
    byte[] b = new byte[100];
    b =  message.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));// Read Binary Message
    }
```